# CPU load of a python daemon

Tags: python, daemon

I wrote a daemon using the [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) library. And it uses about 20% of CPU all the time. Can I somehow check which part of the program uses all this CPU time cause well it actually just waits for userinput? Help is as always much appreciated!

My daemon is started:

python file1:

```
context = daemon.DaemonContext()
context.pidfile = PidFile(pidfile)
with context:
    module.run()
```

python file2:

```
def run():
    end = threading.Event()
    # Do something here then:
    try:
        while not end.isSet():
        # Do some more stuff

    except KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit:
        pass
    # Except some more stuff
```

** EDIT

Maybe you could help me again, now I ran a profiler but can't really tell who the "baddie" is. Here is [my profile results](http://tinypaste.com/eb72245b)

Comment: daemon waiting for user input? Can you post a snippet of the code where it is supposedly waiting?

Comment: what does your do_main_program() (see example of python doc) do ? My guess is it contain something like a "while True:" loop, you should add a call to sleep inside of it if possible, without it your computer try to run that loop as fast as possible.

Comment: @AsTeR yeah, my do_main_program() is replaced with my own method ... i have included a snippet above. And yes, I have already tried sleep and it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach a Python profiler to your software:

http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

... and make the profiler start when the daemon is started. Then let the profiler collect profiling information a while and use a signal sent to process (e.g. SIGUSR1) to make your deamon to dump the profiling data to a file.

http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html

...or alternative write profiling log when the process exits at atexit handler.

Then you can read this file and see which function has most cumulative CPU usage.

Comment: +1 for "a while";  Not so long ago, we were trying to pin down a bottlneck in a highly concurrent daemon.  we let it run for about one minute.  What we saw was that logging was dominating our cpu use.  But that turned out to be unrelated.  shutting it down uncleanly resulted in a few megabytes of tracebacks hitting the logs, one for each of the 100,000 or so jobs it had in flight at the time.  the *real* culprit was that it just had 100,000 jobs in flight at the time. (and so it was supposed to be gobbling up cpu)